# Objective-C get object item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I am getting my object at index like so:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[dataSource cellHolder] objectAtIndex:69]);
```

Now `cellHolder` has at index 69 an item called "Task" and I would like to get the value of "Task".

How would I do that?

Example: `cellHolder[69]["Task"] == "Task 69";`

trying to get that "Task 69" text.

Comment: What class is `Task`? Is it an `NSDictionary`, or something else entirely? We need a bit more information about exactly how your code works here.

Comment: `[cellHolder[69] Task]` ?

Comment: cellHolder is a NSMutableArray

Comment: That isn't what was asked.  An array of WHAT???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the object at index 69, you just do this:

```
cellHolder[69]
```

So if you want to assign it to a variable called `item`, for example:

```
item = cellHolder[69];
```

It's not clear what you mean by *has an item inside of it called "Task"*. If you mean that the item was previous pointed to by a variable named `Task`? If so, that name doesn't really have anything to do with the object stored in the array.

On the other hand, if you mean that the object at index 69 of `cellHolder` has a property named `Task`, then you can get the value of that property of that object as follows. I'll assume for the sake of argument that the type of the value is a string:

```
NSString *taskValue = [cellHolder[69] Task];
```

If the object is a dictionary and one of the keys in that dictionary is `@"Task"`, then you can say:

```
NSString *taskValue = cellHolder[69][@"Task"];
```

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that the bracket notation (i.e `cellHolder[69]`) is equivalent to `[cellHolder objectAtIndex:69];`.

Comment: @user979331 Yes, if `cellHolder` is any kind of NSArray (including NSMutableArray), either syntax (`cellHolder[69]` or `[cellHolder objectAtIndex:69]`) will work. But you haven't told us what *kind* of object you've stored in the array, so it's hard to tell you how to access what you seem to want (although I gave answers for a couple of common situations). If you want help, you really need to provide the information that will help us help you.